# How to call a function only after completing the execution of a thread in angular 5?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular5

> I am trying to call a function after a thread. But the function is
>   getting called before completing thread. Where do I need to change?

```
this._listService.getListById(this.userName)
  .subscribe((response: any) => {     // getting proper response.
    if (response) {
      this._listServiceMod.loadListModel(response); // thread
      this.filterList();
    }
  });



 loadListModel(data:any) {
        const promise = this._listItemService.run(
                        this.loadListItem,
                        {
                            constants: appConstants
                        });
        promise.then((updatedAuthList) => {
            ....
            ....
            this._listItemService.terminate(promise);
        }).catch(e => {
        });;
    }




  filterList(){
  console.log('Inside Filter List')  // prints before completing thread.
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `loadListModel()`?

Comment: What does the `this._listServiceMod.loadListModel` returns

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` feature if you model is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using **async**

```
this._listService.getListById(this.userName)
.subscribe((response: any) => {    
  if (response) {
     this.modelOpen(response);
  }
});

filterList(){
  console.log('Inside Filter List')
}

async modelOpen(response) {
   await this._listServiceMod.loadListModel(response);
   this.filterList();
}
```

[Async](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

Comment: I've tried this way. But still the result is same. In debugger mode, it is identified that the filterList() is called before terminating the promise.

Answer (score 1):

If `filterList` is not dependent on the output of the previous methods, you can make use of RxJs's [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to handle this situation.

```
this._listService.getListById(this.userName).pipe(
  mergeMap(response => this._listServiceMod.loadListModel(response))
).subscribe(response => {
  this.filterList();
});
```

Comment: `filterList` is still firing before `loadListModel()`?

Comment: How about using this? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/skipUntil 
If you need, can write a sample once I am home

Answer (score 1):

Change your `loadListModel` method to following.

```
loadListModel(data:any): Promise<any> {
   let promise = this._listItemService.run(
       this.loadListItem,
       {
          constants: appConstants
       })
   return promise.then((updatedAuthList)=> {
       this._listItemService.terminate(promise);
       return true;
   });
}
```

You can now convert the returned promise to an observable and use `mergeMap` in rxjs to combine two observables

```
this._listService.getListById(this.userName)
 .pipe(
    mergeMap(response => {
      if(response) {
        // Getting the promise
        let promise = this._listServiceMod.loadListModel(response);

        // Converting the promise to an observable by using rxjs's from
        return from(promise);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    )
 )
 .subscribe((res) => {
    // Finally call the filterList
    if(res)
       this.filterList();
 });
```

Checkout this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mergemap-no46pm?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I can't change the loadListModel method since it is used by other components too.

Comment: You can create a duplicate `loadListModel` method for this

Answer (score 1):

change loadListModel to an Observable:

```
this._listServiceMod.loadListModel(response).pipe(
  tap(() =>  this.filterList())
).subscribe()
```

Comment: Tried but filterList() is getting called even before loadListModel starts execution.